# replace files in the command line with specific string

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I need to search (on the whole disk) and replace (where there are matches) one file with another (both in the same path).

Example:

```
  Folder 1
    x*.txt (good) (e.g.: xFile.txt)
    *.txt (bad) (e.g.: File.txt)
```

If there is a match of both files in the same path, i need to delete: `*.txt (e.g.: File.txt)` and rename: `x*.txt (e.g.: xFile.txt)` to `*.txt (e.g.: File.txt)`

Result:

```
 Folder 1
  *.txt (e.g: File.txt... old xFile.txt)
```

I use this command:

```
find -name 'x*.txt' | sed -r 'p;s/g([^\/]*.txt)/\1/' | xargs -d '\n' -n2 mv
```

The problem is that the command does not verify if both files exist (xFile.txt and File.txt in the same path) before executing the order

How can I solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: find `xfile.txt`, and check `[[ -f "${file#x}" ]]` (which strips a leading `x` from the found file and checks to see if _that_ file is present.  If present, then do your switcheroo.

Comment: Alternatively, find `file.txt` and check `[[ -f x"$file" ]]`.  If the replacement is there, do your switcheroo.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Can you explain this with a single command line?

Comment: What if there's a `xx1.txt`, `x1.txt` and `1.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU tools, you could do something like:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
  find . -name '*.txt' -print0 |
  sed -Ez 's|/x([^/]*)$|/\1|' |
  sort -z |
  uniq -zd |
  sed -z 'h;s|.*/|&x|;G' |
  xargs -r0n2 echo mv)
```

That assumes there are not files whose name starts with more than one `x`. For instance, it won't do `mv ./xx.txt ./x.txt`

Answer (score 0):

First, we define a function to do the work for us:

```
switcheroo() {
    [[ -f x"$1" ]] && mv -f x"$1" "$1"
}
export -f switcheroo
```

Now, we use `find` and some black magic to iterate over our foundlings:

```
find . -name \*.txt -execdir bash -c 'switcheroo "$0"' "{}" \;
```

We use `find` to locate all files with a `.txt` extension (this can be refined to suit whatever criteria you like) and in turn run them through the switcheroo process -- we use `[[ ... ]]` to test for the existence of the replacement file, and if it is present, use `mv` to effect the replacement.

Comment: I don't think `find` can run a shell function (but it's simple enough to just put inline)

Comment: Yeah, you do need to use `-execdir sh '[ -f "x$1" ] && mv "x$1" "$1"' sh {} \;`

Comment: Nop. syntax error

Comment: @DopeGhoti Your command does not solve my problem, described in the question. Thanks anyway

Comment: Could you explain how this does not do what you are asking after?

Comment: I run your command (I put it in a script.sh) and it does absolutely nothing that I want it to do.

Comment: Unhelpful.  Please explain what the script does that is different from what you want _and how it differs_.